# I have IIS which can be accessed by IP but I want to access via name

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, dns, iis

I have IIS installed on my windows 8 and set it up and it works fine. 
now I can access it by using IP address (2.2.2.1) but I want to access it by using a name (e.g home-network) and not using IP address. How can I achieve that?  
Also Before this question I made my host file a change but that didn't work.

Comment: Is 2.2.2.1 really the ip you are using? sounds like you're doing something wrong there. That looks like you should be using an address in one of the private IP ranges: 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, or 172.16-31.x.x

Comment: it was 192.168.1.2 but I changed it to 2.2.2.1 to make it easier.

Comment: That won't make things easier. Public IP addresses have actual owners... you won't be able to use that address successfully on the public internet, because you don't own it. You have to use the one assigned to you by your internet provider, which may change from time to time. Look into a service like www.no-ip.org that can automatically map a name you select to your IP address.

Comment: it is home network ,not on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An address like 2.2.2.1 won't make things easier. Public IP addresses have actual owners... you won't be able to use that address successfully on the public internet, because you don't own it. You have to use the address assigned to you by your internet provider.

This assigned address can change from time to time, so you also need to a service that can automatically map a name you select to your IP address. Dyndns used to be a popular choice, but they stopped offering this for a free a while back. I currently use www.no-ip.org. When you set up this service, you will need to install a program that will contact the service's web site and update their listing with your current IP address.

These services will make you choose names that follow a specific format. You'll get to pick any name you want, but it will have to be part of a larger name, like: mychosenname.example.com ...where example.com is name of the service provider. If you don't want to use a name like that, you'll have to buy a domain name. These cost real money; maybe not a lot of money, but you won't be able to get one for free. And if you use your own purchased name, the service may want to charge you a monthly fee for the privilege of forwarding traffic (hosting your dns records) for that name to your IP address.

When the service is up and running, you will also need to set up a port forwarding rule on your internet router, so that requests that come in to the router will be forwarded on to your web server.

After all that is done, you should be able to put the name you selected into any web browser from anywhere in the world and reach your web site... except perhaps your own home, as some routers don't like hairpin routing and won't handle the forward rule back to your web server. This is the case where you might want to update hosts files, or if your router supports create a special dns entry on the router.

Comment: there is a misunderstanding ,my purpose is on wifi home network and not on the internet, as mentioned on tag section of my question the wireless-networking.

Comment: You still need to give your server a local/private address that is in your network's subnet. 2.2.2.1 still won't help you. If you fix that, so that you have a valid address, a hosts file entry should work.

Comment: suppose I changed ip address to what it was before, then what? how can I do that?

Comment: Then you need to put a hosts file entry on all of the computers in your network that maps the name you want to use to that IP address. You also want to make sure this IP address remains permanent on your network, or it will only work until your next dhcp change.

Comment: thank you, this is the answer I expected, it help me a lot.